# How to match a string with a pattern and extract a value from it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I am looking for a way to return certain parts of a string using a pattern.

```
get_value(string: "21-05-2017-01", pattern: "DD-MM-YYYY-NN", substring: "NN") # => "01"
```

---

```
get_value(string: "21-05-2017-01", pattern: "DD-MM-YYYY-NN", substring: "MM") # => "05"
```

Where the number and position of `N`s in the pattern may vary.

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you tried to solve it before asked about solution?

Comment: Can you please provide more examples (different formats) and the expected output? Because at the moment I would suggest using `split('-').last`

Comment: OK, I just added one more example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be as complex as you want probably. But a simple implementation could be.

```
def get_value(string, pattern, substring)
  index = pattern.index(substring)
  raise ArgumentError unless index
  string[index, substring.size]
end

get_value("21-05-2017-01", "DD-MM-YYYY-NN", "NN")
 => "01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_value(hash = {})
  hash[:pattern].split('-').zip(hash[:string].split('-')).map { |k,v| v if k == hash[:substring] }.compact.first
end
```

You can call it as

```
get_value({string: "21-05-2017-01", pattern: "DD-MM-YYYY-NN", substring: "NN"})
# => "01"
```

Comment: In `call` no need to use curly braces :)

Answer (score 1):

To get position of "NN" ins "DD-MM-YYYY-NN" it would be

```
my_index = "DD-MM-YYYY-NN".index("NN")
```

Once you have the index, you can extract the index (for appropriate length) from the string...

```
result = "21-05-2017-01"[my_index, "NN".size]
=> "01"
```

Putting it all together (and handling the case of no match for substring)...

```
def get_value(options)
  return nil if (my_index = options[:pattern].index[options[:substring]) == nil
  string[my_index, options[:substring].size)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One more solution:)

```
def get_value(string:, pattern:, substring:)
  pattern_select = pattern.split('-').zip(string.split('-')).to_h # => {"DD"=>"21", "MM"=>"05", "YYYY"=>"2017", "NN"=>"01"}
  pattern_select.fetch(substring, "Undefined substring: #{substring}")
end
```